# Can I get the TripIt calendar to display events (e.g. in google calendar) usually local times?

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone, tripit

I've happily added my TripIt calendar to google calendar. Unfortunately, it shows all my flights as beginning and ending at the corresponding local California times. This is useless to me --- I add all my remote events at their actual local times, so flight information doesn't mesh with anything else. Moreover, it's no fun looking at a calendar, seeing that your flight leaves at 4:30pm, then getting to the airport 3 hours early because it's actually leaving at 7:30pm EST. (Yes, I actually did this, before realizing what was going on.)

I understand this is a difficult problem (e.g. flight that cross the dateline can easily arrive "before" they depart, necessitating two separate calendar entries for take off and landing, or just an entry with start and finish times confusingly reversed). Is there a technological fix available? Am I just missing some setting at TripIt that will produce the calendar I want? Could I conceivably find some way to wrap the TripIt calendar in another service, that fixes up the times for me?

Comment: At least you didn't miss the flight.. :)

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but I see you never got a good answer to this.  Have you ever solved this?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank, no luck.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: Since my comment, I've been working on this problem with some effort and have concluded that the thing to do is not to fight Google, but to write a little script to pull the events from the Calendar API, and display in a custom web page, with the times adjusted to display in local time, that is, ignoring the time zone.  I'm in the process of writing this now.  If you're interested, I can keep you posted on my progress with this.

Answer (score 1):

Within TripIt navigate to the `Publishing your TripIt Data` section in your `Settings`.  In the Calendar Feed section there is a check box `Automatically adjust time zones in your calendar feed`

I have a flight booked from London to San Francisco. It leaves London at 11:30am(BST) and arrives in San Francisco at 2:30pm (PDT)

When this check box is checked and I import the .ical in to my Google Calendar it shows the flight time as leaving 11:30am and arriving at 10:20pm.

However, when this check box is not checked then it displays the flight time as leaving at 12:30pm and arriving at 3:20pm.

Is this the setting that you are looking for?

Comment: no, it's not the setting I'm looking for. I want my calendar to show that flight leaving at 11:30am, and arriving at 2:30pm! That is, I want the times shown on the calendar to match *my experience of time*! :-)